# How can I call a function using a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

I'm already aware that there's a similar question about this but seems cant make it to work.

Please let me know what needed to do.

example:  ( where the string "test" is the function name )

```
 <script>

  function test(){
  alert("Hello World");
  }
   //is this the right way to call it? 
  window["test"]();


  </script>
```

//no eval pls

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/1270789) demonstrates how to do it. Please describe why you can't get it to work, including any JavaScript console errors.

Comment: It does not work in fiddle. I'm testing in fiddle at the moment when I  asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look in to following

```
var fn = window["test"];
if(typeof fn == 'function') {
    fn();
}
```

Comment: @ronell Please see modified answer

Comment: Hi Pawan, I'm expecting an alert when I reload the page. Here's the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uxskW/3/

Comment: Please see the fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/uxskW/5/ You have to write this is head section and remove one extra = which i put by mistake , silly typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Eval is what you need. Example:

```
<script>
    eval("alert('hello')");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't want to use eval.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<script>

function test(){
alert("Hello World");
}
var func = 'test'
this[func]();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work. Here is is an answer to a similar question
[How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: yeah, but it didn't work.. I already checked the page before asking. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Pawan's answer is right, it doesn't work in fiddle because fiddle wraps code into $(window).on("load") event. Try it in normal page. Sorry, can't coment, low reputation